# Using a mixin on two components: it calls the method on only the first component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

I have two components that need to share a method. I used a mixin for this method and added the mixin to both components. When I click on the second component it fires off the method on the first component instead of the second one - in this case, it opens the top drop down and not the second drop down.

Here is a snippet of my code...

```js
// Mixins

var showDropdownMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
      activeTrigger: false,
      dropdown: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showDropdown: function(){
      if(this.dropdown == false){
        this.dropdown = true;
        this.activeTrigger = true;
        TweenMax.fromTo(
          "#dropdown",
          0.55,
          {
            autoAlpha: 0,
            y: -10
          },
          {
            autoAlpha: 1,
            y: 0,
            ease: Power2.easeOut
          }
        );
      }else{
        this.dropdown = false;
        this.activeTrigger = false;
         TweenMax.to(
          "#dropdown",
          0.2,
          {
            autoAlpha: 0,
            y: -10,
            ease: Power2.easeOut
          });
      }

    }
  }
}








//Global Components

Vue.component('photo-questions', {
  data() {
    return {
      filters: [
        "Q2: Message: Vermont Village 8oz Sipping Vinegar products have had issues with…",
        "Q10: This is the second photo question.",
        "Q11: This is the third photo question.",
        "Q12: This is the fourth photo question.",
        "Q13: This is the fifth photo question.",
        "Q14: This is the sixth photo question.",
        "Q15: This is the seventh photo question.",
        "Q16: This is the eighth photo question.",
        "Q17: This is the ninth photo question.",
        "Q18: This is the tenth photo question.",
        "Q19: This is the eleventh photo question.",
        "Q20: This is the twelfth photo question."
      ],
      checkedFilters: [],
      allSelected: true,
      selectAllText: 'Select All'
    };
  },
  template: '#photo-questions-template',
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.filters.filter(item => {
        return item.toLowerCase();
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectAll: function() {
      this.checkedFilters = [];
      this.selectAllText = this.selectAllText == "Select All" ? 'Clear All' : 'Select All';
      if (this.allSelected) {
        for (filter in this.filters) {
          this.checkedFilters.push(this.filters[filter].toString());
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mixins: [showDropdownMixin]
})



Vue.component('associated-questions', {
  data() {
    return {
      filters: [
        "Q2: Message: Vermont Village 8oz Sipping Vinegar products have had issues with…",
        "Q10: This is the second photo question.",
        "Q11: This is the third photo question.",
        "Q12: This is the fourth photo question.",
        "Q13: This is the fifth photo question.",
        "Q14: This is the sixth photo question.",
        "Q15: This is the seventh photo question.",
        "Q16: This is the eighth photo question.",
        "Q17: This is the ninth photo question.",
        "Q18: This is the tenth photo question.",
        "Q19: This is the eleventh photo question.",
        "Q20: This is the twelfth photo question."
      ],
      checkedFilters: [],
      allSelected: true,
      selectAllText: 'Select All'
    };
  },
  template: '#associated-questions-template',
  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      return this.filters.filter(item => {
        return item.toLowerCase();
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectAll: function() {
      this.checkedFilters = [];
      this.selectAllText = this.selectAllText == "Select All" ? 'Clear All' : 'Select All';
      if (this.allSelected) {
        for (filter in this.filters) {
          this.checkedFilters.push(this.filters[filter].toString());
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mixins: [showDropdownMixin]
})





//Main Vue Instance

function run_app(){

    const searchFilters = new Vue({
        el: '#searchFilters',
        data: {
            title: "Vue is working"
        },
    });

};

window.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    run_app()
});
```

```css
/**********************
     Global Styles
***********************/

body {

}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
}


*, :after, :before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/**********************
     Tab/Container
***********************/

#active-tab {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #2CACDF;
    border: 1px solid #2CACDF;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

#active-tab:hover {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #2CACDF;
    border: 1px solid #2CACDF;
}

.nav-tabs li a {
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search-container {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding : 25px 15px;
}

.search-container select {
    width: 100%;
}





/**********************
     Search/Filters
***********************/

.search-container input {
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.checkbox-select {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}

.checkbox-select li {
    list-style: none;
}

.checkbox-select__trigger {
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0 25px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.checkbox-select__trigger.isActive svg {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.checkbox-select__trigger svg {
  width: 1rem;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.checkbox-select__title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.checkbox-select__dropdown {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 12px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.checkbox-select__dropdown .simplebar-scrollbar {
  width: 3px;
  right: 1px;
}

.checkbox-select__col {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 25px 25px 0px 25px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.checkbox-select__select-all label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox-select__select-all input {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-select__filters-wrapp {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.checkbox-select__check-wrapp {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkbox-select__check-wrapp input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-select__check-wrapp input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: padding 0.25s ease;
}

.checkbox-select__check-wrapp input[type="checkbox"] + label:after {
  border: solid 1px #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: 3px;
  content: "";
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.checkbox-select__check-wrapp input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  background-color: #2cacdF;
  opacity: 0;
  will-change: transform;
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.checkbox-select__check-wrapp input[type="checkbox"] + label:hover {
  padding-left: 32px;
}

.checkbox-select__check-wrapp input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a>Review Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="active-tab">Mass Approvals Page</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="searchFilters" class="search-container container-fluid">

            <div class="col-md-12">

                <label for="project-id">Project ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="project-id" name="project-id">

                <label for="job-id">Job ID:</label>
                <input type="text" id="job-id" name="job-id">

                <label for="all-photo-questions">All Photo Questions:</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="all-photo-questions" name="all-photo-questions">

                <button>Reset Filters</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <photo-questions></photo-questions>
                <associated-questions></associated-questions>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

            </div>

        </div>




        <!-- Component Templates -->

        <script type="text/x-template" id="photo-questions-template">
            <div class="checkbox-select">
                <div class="checkbox-select__trigger" :class="{ isActive: activeTrigger }" @click="showDropdown()">
                    <span class="checkbox-select__title">Photo Questions:</span>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129 129"><path d="M121.3 34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8 0l-51 51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8 0-1.6 1.6-1.6 4.2 0 5.8l53.9 53.9c.8.8 1.8 1.2 2.9 1.2 1 0 2.1-.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2.1-5.8z"/></svg>
                </div>
                <div id="dropdown" class="checkbox-select__dropdown">
                    <div class="checkbox-select__col">
                        <div class="checkbox-select__select-all">
                            <label for="selectAll">{{selectAllText}}</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" @click="selectAll" v-model="allSelected">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox-select__info">
                            {{checkedFilters.length}} SELECTED
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="customScroll" class="checkbox-select__filters-wrapp" data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
                        <li v-for="(filter, index) in filteredList">
                              <div class="checkbox-select__check-wrapp">
                                  <input :id="index" class="conditions-check" v-model="checkedFilters" :value="filter" type="checkbox">
                                  <label :for="index">{{filter}}</label>
                              </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>





        <script type="text/x-template" id="associated-questions-template">
            <div class="checkbox-select">
                <div class="checkbox-select__trigger" :class="{ isActive: activeTrigger }" @click="showDropdown()">
                    <span class="checkbox-select__title">Associated Questions:</span>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 129 129"><path d="M121.3 34.6c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8 0l-51 51.1-51.1-51.1c-1.6-1.6-4.2-1.6-5.8 0-1.6 1.6-1.6 4.2 0 5.8l53.9 53.9c.8.8 1.8 1.2 2.9 1.2 1 0 2.1-.4 2.9-1.2l53.9-53.9c1.7-1.6 1.7-4.2.1-5.8z"/></svg>
                </div>
                <div id="dropdown" class="checkbox-select__dropdown">
                    <div class="checkbox-select__col">
                        <div class="checkbox-select__select-all">
                            <label for="selectAll">{{selectAllText}}</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" @click="selectAll" v-model="allSelected">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox-select__info">
                            {{checkedFilters.length}} SELECTED
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="customScroll" class="checkbox-select__filters-wrapp" data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
                        <li v-for="(filter, index) in filteredList">
                              <div class="checkbox-select__check-wrapp">
                                  <input :id="index" class="conditions-check" v-model="checkedFilters" :value="filter" type="checkbox">
                                  <label :for="index">{{filter}}</label>
                              </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements with the same id: dropdown.  It looks like TweenMax queries the built page to find where to attach the menu, and just goes with the first one it finds.

You might make the id for each element unique, and pass the id as a parameter on your showDropdown method.